# JQuery Progress Bar for Zencoder Conversions

Tags: jquery, notifications, zencoder

I want to configure a jquery progress bar to load from zencoder API notifications about a video conversion. The API sends the notification to a specified URL in the form of json or xml, but I can't figure out where its going if at all. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify what notifications you want, and where you'd like them to be sent. The [guides](https://app.zencoder.com/docs/guides/getting-started/notifications) on this are really helpful for getting started. In a nutshell, you can have it POST or email a notification for the whole job, individual outputs, or both.

However, these notifications are only sent when a job or output is completed, so it wouldn't help you too much for a progress bar. For that you can query the API for [job progress](https://app.zencoder.com/docs/api/jobs/progress) and update your progress bar accordingly.

Comment: I was able to solve this problem a month ago but I think your answer would have lead me in the right direction. I solved the problem differently, and I may formalize that answer and post it in this thread. If I don't have a chance to do so and the next couple days, I'll give you the answer cred, but for now, here's an up. Thank you.